# Safari opens on drive dismount

Tags: hard-drive, safari, macos, eject

For some reason, sometimes when I dismount/eject a physical drive, Safari launches in the background. This behavior has occurred even in safe mode, in a guest account, with nothing else running. I've experienced it happening with SD cards, USB hard drives, and thumb drives.

I've spent an hour on the phone with an Apple tech to no avail, and I've spent quite a bit of time on my own trying to narrow it down. What could be causing this, and how can I stop it?

I'm running Sierra on a 2015 rMBP.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I can think of a system-level daemon -- fire up Terminal and try:

```
$ sudo fs_usage -w > ~/Desktop/eject_log.txt
```

Then dismount and let Safari open up.  Back to terminal, `^C` (ctrl-c).
Open up the log file and see what you find.

Comment: Thanks for the advice — unfortunately it only happens occasionally, but I'll see if I can catch the log next time.

Comment: Ah crap.  The only time when a problem not happening is actually a bad thing.  Well, that command will log events (file system, network etc) and throw it all into a file nicely for you to go through.  Hopefully it'll give you somewhere to start.